# I just bought an iMac with Mavericks pre-installed, can i go back to Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos

Just bought an iMac with Mavericks pre-installed and some of my software isn't working. After looking into it Mavericks is causing quite a few problems.
Is there any way of reverting it back to Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 2):

Older OS X versions might not include all drivers/kernel extensions required on current hardware so the general answer is **No**.

Apple has a nice article elaborating [*why* this is a bad idea in general](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2186), but if you want to learn and have a backup of all your data, you could always try and see how far you get.

Also, just because your Mac shipped with Mavericks, doesn't necessarily mean that model isn't fully supported on an earlier version. You could check your [exact model and determine whether your intended OS + Hardware combination](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1159) is an exception to the general rule.

Assuming your iMac is the one marketed by Apple as Late 2013 - they yes, it will support installation of OS X 10.8.4 - Build 12E4022.

Having said that, an easy way out would be to run Mountain Lion in a VM (both VMware and Parallels will do).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to set up an OS X VM using Fusion ? There would seem to be a bootstrap problem when it comes to installing the OS ?

Comment: Please ask a new question for this using the "Ask Question" link on top. Also you first may want to have a look at the Fusion website, they may have an FAQ for this.

Comment: Thanks - I've been using Fusion for any years for Linux and Windows VM on the Mac, but didn't know you could set up an OS X VM too - I'll try the Fusion web site as you suggest.